# TypeError: undefined is not an boject (evaluating '_ref$i18n.currentLanguage')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, localization

I'm using `redux-react-native-i18n` for Localization.

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref$i18n.currentLanguage')

Here is my code in store/index.js

```
import { i18nReducer, i18nActions, Loc } from 'redux-react-native-i18n';

reducers.i18n = i18nReducer

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);

const dictionaries = {
    'en-US': {
        'oh': 'Order History',
    },
    'ko-KR': {
        'oh': '주문내역',
    },
    //...

}

store.dispatch( i18nActions.setDictionaries( dictionaries ) )
```

Set Language (store.index.js - continue)

```
const languages = [
    {
        code: 'en-US',
        name: 'english'
    },
    {
        code: 'ko-KR',
        name: 'Korean'
    },
    //...
]

store.dispatch( i18nActions.setLanguages( languages ) )
store.dispatch( i18nActions.setCurrentLanguage( 'en-US' ) ) <<<It's not working?

export default store;
```

Here I'm calling `<Loc />` Text component which translate to the current language.

`<H2 style={styles.locationTitle}><Loc locKey="oh"/></H2>` <- error here

I did `console.log('hi')` in the store and it seems my store is working correctly. I'm running this on Android.

Comment: The react-native pkg link: https://github.com/derzunov/redux-react-native-i18n/blob/master/src/LocRN.js  ; Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use `combineReducers( reducers )`. Seems that your variable "reducers" is an object. But it must be a function - https://redux.js.org/api-reference/createstore